# Why does `clojure.spec.alpha/every-kv` accept `[]` as a valid "associative collection"?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

We run this:

Definition of lovely specs:

```
(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s :refer [valid? explain conform]])

(s/def ::fun-key integer?)
(s/def ::fun-value keyword?)
(s/def ::fun
   (s/every-kv ::fun-key ::fun-value))
```

Testing time:

```
(valid? ::fun {})
;=> true
(valid? ::fun {:a :b})
;=> false
(valid? ::fun {0 :b})
;=> true
```

This is fine. But now!

```
(valid? ::fun [])
;=> true
```

The above is weird, IMHO it should fail. So it's kinda sitting on the true/false event horizon, but I would expect `false`.

Let's test around:

```
; The following is expected:

(valid? ::fun [0 :b])
;=> false

; The following is expected though I don't get the failure explanation.
; I suppose it tries to (for [x [0 :b]] (something)) then fails at getting
; 0th and 1th on the x because they are scalars not key-value pairs.

(explain ::fun [0 :b])
;=> Execution error (UnsupportedOperationException) at 
;=> foo.bar/fn (form-init514798422823080150.clj:2).
;=> nth not supported on this type: Long

; Same as above

(valid? ::fun [:a :b])
;=> false

(explain ::fun [:a :b])
;=> Execution error (UnsupportedOperationException) at
;=> foo.bar/fn (form-init514798422823080150.clj:2).
;=> nth not supported on this type: Keyword
```

Ok, fine!

> ```
> Usage: (every-kv kpred vpred & opts)
>
> like 'every' but takes separate key and val preds and works on
> associative collections.
>
> Same options as 'every', :into defaults to {}
> ```

So why does spec's [every-kv](https://clojure.github.io/spec.alpha/clojure.spec.alpha-api.html#clojure.spec.alpha/every-kv) think `[]` is a valid associative collection?

I can see that a vector is "associative" in the sense of associating an integer key (the index) to a value, but still!

Comment: I guess it is because `PesistentVector implements IKVReduce and IMapIterator`
If you need your object to be a map, you gotta force it with `map?` for example

Comment: nevertheless, it is a bit surprising indeed

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer That how I found out ... I had `map?` in a spec and it failed correctly on seeing `[]`. As the `map?` was `and`-ed with `every-kv` I thought "I probably don't need this `map?`" and so removed it. Test case failure ensued as a bad structure passed the spec.

Comment: One can do `(s/every-kv kpred vpred :kind map?)` instead of `(s/and map? (s/every-kv kpred vpred)`. Nicer that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually surprised it doesn't work on `[:a]` since that is an "associative" collection with integer keys and keyword values:

```
(s/valid? ::fun [])
;; => true

;; why this fails??
(s/valid? ::fun [:a])
;; => false
(associative? [:a])
;; => true

;; But if works for a vector of tuples
(s/valid? ::fun [[0 :a]])
;; => true
```

However, I guess the "problem" lies in the [implementation](https://github.com/clojure/spec.alpha/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/spec/alpha.clj#L572) where it calls `every` using a 'tuple' predicate. For empty vector, it's trivially satisfied but for non-empty vectors the element itself isn't a 'tuple'.